# Customizing ListView via XML Problem

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have a simple ListActivity that uses a ListAdapter that I'd like to customize the ListView for.  Here is my onCreate, where I specify to use a View rather than using the default ListView generated by setListAdapter():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set the listview, empty listview
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

    // set the list properties
    getListView().setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    .
    .
    .
    <code snipped>
    .
    .
    .

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

You can see that I am setting the emptyView as well.  Here is the XML file main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView  
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" />
    <TextView 
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/message_empty_list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that the ListView, while applying the dividerHeight correctly, is ignoring the :fadingEdge directive when it is in the XML; however, if I set the fadingEdge programatically, it works, i.e.:

```
getListView().setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
```

Any ideas why the listview would be ignoring the fadingEdge specifically?  Am I doing something incorrectly that could be leading to this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```

should be

```
android:id="@iandroid:id/list"
```

I'm not even sure why that compiles.

This is how you should be using custom xml for listactivities.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="No data found"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I originally had it as android:id/list as I had expected it to be, but it wasn't working then either... so I did a search and came across a page here recommending changing it to @id/android:list... and of course now I can't find that page.  Anyways, short answer is it still doesn't work changing the android:id

Comment: FYI, I also changed my XML to a FrameLayout vs a LinearLayout for the parent root container, with no change in the results, still isn't picking up the android:fadingEdge property.

Comment: I'll bet the listview is overriding the fading edge attribute since that's how listview handles it by default. Try changing it in code.

Comment: If I don't specify any XML, the ListAdapter generates the ListView automatically and, correctly.  It's only when I specify the XML layout that the default behavior, such as fading edges, stops.  I am currently changing it in the code, but seems strange to have XML defining SOME attributes of the ListView, and the others hard-coded into the app.  Thanks.